# Barcode image not displaying in html img tag

Tags: php, html, barcode

I need to take printout the barcode, I'm having item list in datatable and i have button to take print the item details with barcode, but some times barcode displaying in print preview and some times not displaying in print preview. Below is my code,

```
function printitembarcode(barcodeimg, shortname, grosswt, stwt, iscode)
{
    if(iscode == 1){
        var printContent = "<div><table id='"+ barcodeimg +"' width='300px' height='40px' border='0'><tbody><tr><td width='120px' style='text-align:left;align:left;margin-left:10px !important;'><img src='"+ base_url + "assets/img/barcode/"+ barcodeimg +".png' alt='Bar Code' style='height:37px !important;' /></td><td width='120px' style='font-weight:bold;margin-left:20px;'> CODE : "+ parseInt((stwt)*1000) +"<br>"+ shortname +"<br> Wt : " + grosswt + " Gm </td><td width='60px'></td></tr></tbody></table></div>";
    }else{
        var printContent = "<div><table id='"+ barcodeimg +"' width='300px' height='40px' border='0'><tbody><tr><td width='120px' style='text-align:left;align:left;margin-left:10px; !important;'><img src='"+ base_url + "assets/img/barcode/"+ barcodeimg+".png' alt='Bar Code' style='height:37px !important;' /></td><td width='120px' style='font-weight:bold;margin-left:20px;'>"+ shortname +"<br> G.Wt : " + grosswt + " Gm <br> S.Wt : "+ stwt + " Gm </td><td width='60px'></td></tr></tbody></table></div>";
    }
    //console.log(printContent);
    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=30000,top=30000,width=0,height=0');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><style type="text/css">@page { size: auto; margin: 0mm; } body { font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif; font-size: 11px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; font-weight:bold; } html {  margin: 0px; } table{ font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif; font-size: 11px !important; margin-left:0px; margin-top:2px;margin-right:1px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid #ddd; } table td{ height:38px; border: 0px solid #ddd; } table td:first-child { text-align: left; margin-left:2px !important; }​ p{ margin-top:1px;}@media print{@page { margin: 0mm !important; } font-size: 11px !important; font-weight:bold; table td:first-child { text-align: left;margin-left:2px !important; }​ } </style></head><body style="font-size: 11px;" onload="window.print()">'+ printContent +'</body></html>');
    //printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

I have below code to generate barcode in server, Used PHP codeigniter

```
public function set_barcode($code)
    {
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        $code = str_pad($code, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code, 'barHeight' => 25), array());
        //$store_image = imagepng($file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/img/barcode/{$code}.png");
        $store_image = imagepng($file, $this->config->item('documentroot')."assets/img/barcode/{$code}.png");

    }
```

Please help anyone to display barcode for whenever i click on print button without issue.Now sometimes coming to display some times disappear the barcode.

Comment: how do these two bits of code relate to each other? done any basic debugging, like looking at the generated html and seeing if the various urls are correct and working?

Comment: If i console url and run in browser means it getting image, not issue in url